# zsh vi mode: browse recent commands starting with

Tags: zsh, vi-mode

I've recently switched to vi-mode in my zsh and there is a feature from emacs-mode that I cannot find how to do in vi-mode.
The feature is browsing history by lines starting by something I've already typed.
For example if I type `vi` and press <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> then I browse through my recent commands starting with `vi`.
Is it even possible with vi-mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*emacs-mode* and *vi-mode* are only different presets of key bindings. Any widget can be bound in any mode.

The widgets in question here are `history-beginning-search-backward` (presumably for <kbd>↑</kbd>) and `history-beginning-search-forward` (for <kbd>↓</kbd>).

To bind them to the up and down keys in `vicmd` mode, you just need to run

```
bindkey '^[[A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '^[[B' history-beginning-search-forward
```

- Note 1: This overwrites the default setting for those keys.
- Note 2: `^[[A` and `^[[B` may not be the correct codes for your terminal.

  - either Find the correct ones by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by the key in question.
  - or make use of the associative array `terminfo` to retrieve the correct binding (my thanks to [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) for his comment on this):

    ```
    bindkey "$terminfo[kcuu1]" history-beginning-search-backward
    bindkey "$terminfo[kcud1]" history-beginning-search-backward
    ```

    `kcuu1` and `kcud1` are the *capability names* for <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>, respectively. You can get a list of possible capabilies and their names from the `terminfo(5)` manpage (`man 5 terminfo`). The associative array `terminfo` uses the names from the "Cap-name" column as keys.

Comment: See also `$terminfo[kcuu1]` to get the sequence for the Up key from the terminfo database.